why does findOne method on sequelize just compare on the Id column of table
so this code that is a route I have created using sequelize library on mysql database
const { user_name } = req.params;
const user = await User.findOne({ where: { username: user_name } });

it has to compare user_name value with username column on the table and return value based on it's true or false, but everytime I sent a request the query is like that it compares the value with the Id column, what is wrong with that?
returned query after request:
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `username`, `email`, `password`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Users` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`id` = 'sadegh';


Please show the Sequelize model definition
